# Difference between a 'string' vs. 'buffer text' in search commands when using line breaks (\n)

Tags: vim

The following description is found in the line break (`\n`) section of the pattern and search commands in the official vim documentation.
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms

```
\n  matches an end-of-line              */\n*
    When matching in a string instead of buffer text a literal newline
    character is matched.
```

I don't understand

> When matching in a string instead of buffer text a literal newline character is matched.

When can this be detected?

I have done the following experiment. I put the following in a file and typed `/\n` on the vim command line, but it did not match a literal newline character in all cases.

```
"\n"
'\n'
\n
```

Comment: @mattb, yes that's 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'string' it doesn't mean text in the buffer that's surrounded by quotes, but rather the `{string}` argument that you would pass to the 'substitute' function. See `:help substitute()`

Comment: Thanks.
Am I right in using it this way?

`:echo substitute("foo\n", "\n", "bar", "")`
`foobar`

Comment: Yes, as long as you use the correct quotes.